# SAS Keep maximum value by ID

Tags: sas

Each ID has several instances, and each instance has a different value.  I would like the final output to be the maximum value per ID. So the initial dataset is:

```
 ID     Value
 1      100
 1      7
 1      65
 2      12
 2      97
 3      82
 3      54
```

And the output will be:

```
 ID     Value
 1      100
 2      97
 3      82
```

I tried running proc sort twice thinking that the first sort would get things in the proper order so that nodupkey on the second sort would get rid of the right values. This did not work.

```
 proc sort work.data; by id value descending; run;
 proc sort work.data nodupkey; by id; run;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach should have worked fine but it looks like you have a syntax error - did you forget to check your log?  The descending keyword needs to go before the variable you want to sort in descending order.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=tmp;
  by sex descending height;
run;

proc sort data=tmp out=final nodupkey;
  by sex;
run;
```

Also - in case you're not familiar with SQL, I strongly suggest that you should learn it as it will simplify many data manipulation tasks.  This can also be solved in a single SQL step:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as
  select sex,
         max(height) as height
  from sashelp.class
  group by sex
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: He also left off `data=` .

Comment: @Joe - Ha I didn't notice that.  I thought you must have taken an early start to the long weekend because there were a few unanswered q's. =P

Answer (score 2):

My preferred solution:

```
proc means data=have noprint;
  class id;
  var value;
  output out=want max(value)=;
run;
```

Should be a lot faster than two sorts.

Comment: This is fine for reasonably small datasets, but if you have millions of distinct IDs you may run into memory issues with this approach.

Comment: PROC MEANS will use disk space for much of the work; it will run into problems calculating quantiles (like the median) for very large datasets, but I've never run into memory problems with PROC MEANS calculating simple statistics, like MAX, and I've used it on datasets with millions of IDs many times.

Comment: Could this approach work if you have more than two variables in the by of the first sort of the other answer?

Comment: Sure, the class statement would handle that (and the TYPES statement would be required to get only the needed information, or maybe WAYS).